# SQL JOIN query writing

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to write a simple query involving two tables.  The "person" table has a unique `person_id` and a `name`, and the "friends" table has a `person_id` and a `friend_id` which is a FK to a `person_id` in the person table.

```
person:
<PK> int person_id 
varchar[45] name

friends: 
<PK> int person_id
<PK> int friend_id
```

I want to select the name of all of person 1's friends.

I can do this easily using an `IN` statement:

```
SELECT p.name FROM person p WHERE p.person_id IN (SELECT f.friend_id FROM friends f WHERE f.person_id = 1);
```

However, I am not proficient at writing `JOIN` statements.  Can somebody help me write the equivalent join?

Clearly this is a contrived example, but I have tried with my real data and am conceptually missing something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT p.name, f.friend_id
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN friends AS f ON p.person_id = f.person_id
WHERE p.person_id = 1
```

This joins the two tables together using `p.person_id = f.person_id`

If a person has no friends, you won't get any rows back - if you don't want this then use LEFT JOIN and you'll get one row with a NULL `friend_id`.

Edit: if you want to join friends back on to person:

```
SELECT p.name AS person_name, friend.name AS friend_name
FROM person AS p                                         -- Our person
INNER JOIN friends AS f ON p.person_id = f.person_id     -- the join table
INNER JOIN person AS friend on f.friend_id = friend.id   -- Join back on person again
WHERE p.person_id = 1
```

Maybe you need a 3-way join like this for your app, but more usually you'd only need a 2-way as above, or like this:

```
SELECT p.name, f.friend_id
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN friends AS f ON p.person_id = f.friend_id
WHERE f.person_id = 1
```

This will give you the names of all the people that are friends with person_id 1 (but not person_id 1's name)

Answer (score 6):

```
select 
    p.name,
    p2.name as friend_name,
from
    person p 
    inner join friends f on p.person_id = f.person_id
    inner join person p2 on f.friend_id = p2.person_id -- friends
where
    p.person_id = <your criteria>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.name FROM person p 
INNER JOIN friends f ON f.friend_id = p.person_id
WHERE f.person_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name
from person p, friends f
where f.friend_id = p.person_id
and f.person_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Tony Andrews got it right, except that I think that the correct syntax puts the source table on the left and the joined table on the right...

```
SELECT p.name FROM person p 
INNER JOIN friends f ON p.person_id = f.friend_id
WHERE f.person_id = 1
```

This will return the `[person.name]` field of all records where the `[person.person_id]` value is found in the `[friends.friend_id]` field AND the `[friends.person_id]` fields equals 1....everyone that is a friend of [1] will exist in the filtered person table when they're joined together and limited to `friends.person_id=[1]`