# sql query using two tables

Tags: sql, join

Table one:

```
|user_id|hotel_id|  
|  1    |  4     |
|  1    |  5     | 
|  2    |  6     |
|  4    |  7     |
```

table two:

```
|hotel_id|hotel_name|more_ifo| 
|    4   | bla      |bla     |
|    5   | bla      |bla     |
|    6   |more bla  |bla     |
|    7   | bla      |bla     |
```

I want to get all the info of the hotels that a certain user have for example user one hotels 4 and 5 .. any help? I tried using join but I guess I'm not using it correctly..?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334852/sql-join-query-writing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*, hotels.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN hotels
ON users.hotel_id = hotels.hotel_id
```

Note that using `*` in a `SELECT` clause is considered bad practice; I only do it here as part of an example of using joins.

If you want to search for the hotels associated with a specific user, just add a `WHERE` clause to that effect:

```
SELECT users.*, hotels.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN hotels
ON users.hotel_id = hotels.hotel_id
WHERE users.user_id = ?
```

Comment: it wouldn't just give me all the hotels? i'm looking for the hotels of just user one should'nt there be a "where" somewhere?

Comment: Please refresh.  I updated my answer to include such a query before you commented.

Answer (score 2):

`t1` is alias for `table one` and
`t2` is alias `table two`

```
select t1.user_id,t2.hotel_id,t2.hotel_name,t2.more_info
from table_one t1 INNER JOIN table_two t2
ON t1.hotel_id=t2.hotel_id
where t1.user_id=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could query all hotels for a user with an `exists` clause:

```
select  *
from    hotels
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    users
        where   users.hotel_id = hotels.hotel_id
                and users.user_id = @YourUserId
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select B.more_ifo
From table_one A, table_two B
Where A.hotel_id = B.hotel_id
```

This isn't work ?

After that;

```
Select B.more_ifo
From table_one A, table_two B
Where A.hotel_id = B.hotel_id
AND A.hotel_id IN (4, 5)
```